# How can I set daternagepicker to allow local datetime selection instead of utc

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker, datetimeoffset

I am using Dan Grossman's daterangepicker to display a range of datetime for users selection. Unfortunately the datetime that is selected and passed to the backend is in UTC and as such is being saved to database. I need to set the daterangepicker to display the local time based on the time zone selected earlier. Does anyone know how to deal with this?
I tried adding timeZone option ("01:00") but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
$('form .date_available').daterangepicker({
  timeZone: "01:00",
  timePicker: true,
  timePickerIncrement: 30,
  minDate: currentDate,
  minTime: currentTime,
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A',
  formatTime: 'h:mm A',
  formatDate: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the time zone for the Server in config/application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

OR you have a timezone change for users you can add the following to application_controller.rb, and you should save in settings the user timezone:

```
around_filter :user_time_zone

def user_time_zone(&block)
  if user_signed_in?
    Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
  else
    Time.use_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)', &block)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed but Rails saves 'created_at' time correctly in UTC and the only problem is this one form. The datetime selected should be sent to the server either as local time and converted to UTC on the backend or converted from localtime to UTC just before it is sent to the server. For example when user chooses 3.pm in the date picker in a local time in a timezone +1:00, should should be saved in db as 2.pm UTC but it is being saved as 3.pm UTC because the selected date in being selected as UTC.

Comment: Yes, i understand you can do something like the following as playing with Timezones in javascript not that fun.

dt = DateTime.now
=> Mon, 20 Dec 2010 18:59:43 +0100
dt = dt.change(:offset => "+0000")
=> Mon, 20 Dec 2010 18:59:43 +0000

this will change the offset without effecting the date and time.

Comment: That seems to work fine even as a temporary solution. Thanks!